# Initializing Codeigniter Utilities inside contstructor on Custom Class

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been doing CI for a few months and got to a point where i wanted to create my own library class on CI. Now, my problem is that i can't seem to get the instance of CI in order for me to utilize its native resources. i've done this.

```
class MyClass{
     protected $instance;
     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->$instance = &get_instance(); <-- this is what i did (theoretically speaking)

     }
  }
```

**Other things i've tried**

```
class MyClass{

     protected $instance = &get_instance(); <-- reports a syntax error on Apatana

     public function __construct()
     {


     }
  }
```

Anyone of you out there who can give me a better idea on how to get the instance (initializing it a one point on the source code) <-- being said that, i wanted to get the instance only once and use that all over on my **Class**

Comment: `protected $instance = &get_instance();` not supported in `PHP`

Comment: so how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use it in this way
in constructor
$this->ci = & get_instance();

then you can use it like 
$this->ci->load->model();
```

Comment: hmmm it solved the problem.. but got anymore ideas? i think $this->ci->load is a bit long.. or am i just too lazy hehe but anyway im open for any ideas though..

Comment: @lemoncodes what i mean is you can use this code, but replace $this->ci (which is bad to read) with $CI

Comment: yo man, replacing $this->ci with $CI is ok when u want to use $CI on the constructor.. But when you use $CI in other function, it cannpt see $CI its outside the scope